# typeorm querybuilder innerjoin only gives the first element

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm

I have this querybuilder here:

```
this.repository.createQueryBuilder('house')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('house.items', 'items')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('house.owner', 'owner')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('house.rooms', 'rooms')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('rooms.name', 'name')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('rooms.roomitems', 'roomitems')
    .where({ 'house.id': id })
    .getOne().then(house => {
        // house.rooms.length === 1
    })
```

I get my full object with this; a list of items, the owner and a list of rooms with all properties.

The problem is that the list of Rooms only contains one item. When I do use .find, I find four rooms.

what do I do wrong?

---

Edit:

```
this.repository.findOne(id, {relation: ['rooms']}).then(house => {
    // house.rooms.length === 4
})
```

Comment: have u got any solution for this ??

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell without seeing the whole database, but it could be linked with the difference with innerjoin and leftjoin in SQL.

With innerJoin, only the element with both side of the relation are returned,
and with leftjoin, element who do not have a right side of the relation are shown with Null in place of the right element.

you should try doing your query with leftJoinAndSelect to see if it's return all the rooms. If it does, I guessed correctly.